# Appending to list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuple which looks like this:

```
    my_list = [(["$"], 1.5)]
```

And I also  have these valuables stored as variables:

```
    val1 = "#"
    val2 = 3.0
```

I want to be able to append val1 to the list within the tuple, and multiply val2 with the second element in the tuple. It should look like this:

```
    [(["$", "#"], 4.5)]
```

so far I have this:

```
    for item in my_list:
        for i in item:
            i[0].append(val1)
            i[1] = i[1] * val2
```

But so far this is not working, Is there a another way I can do this?

Comment: What Zondo said. You can mutate the mutable items in a tuple but you can't replace tuple items. So you can mutate the list, but you can't touch the float.

Comment: Thankyou, I will definitely remember that next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tuples are immutable.  Therefore, you must create a new one:

```
for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    item[0].append("#")
    my_list[i] = item[0], item[1] * 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer man :). As a beginner, I often forget the subtleties of immutability in different data structures such as tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have to create new tuples anyway, why not create a new list while you are at it? This will allow for a simple list-comprehension:

```
>>> my_list = [(["$"], 1.5), (["@"], 2.5)]
>>> val1 = "#"
>>> val2 = 3.0
>>> new_list = [(x+[val1],y*val2) for x,y in my_list]
>>> new_list
[(['$', '#'], 4.5), (['@', '#'], 7.5)]
```

Comment: The OP _might_ want to keep the old list if the code has more than one reference to it. Of course, that's easily done: `my_list[:] = [(x+[val1],y*val2) for x,y in my_list]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @John Coleman. It's surprising how many different ways there are of doing things.